# Return parameter on Close[X] button with DialogResult

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have a dialog which returns a `IList` value for the key `CreatedGroups`.

I can already return said string when the user presses a certain button on the dialog to close it.

```cs
private void CloseDialogOK()
{
    CanCloseDialog = true;

    DialogParameters parm = new DialogParameters();
    parm.Add("CreatedGroups", _createdGroups);
    RequestClose?.Invoke(new DialogResult(ButtonResult.OK, parm));
}
```

However, as I cannot remove the [X] Close button located on the dialog's top right, how can I attach the same method above to the [X] Close button?

Comment: You can remove the close button either by using a custom style for the existing dialog window or creating your own dialog window.

Comment: Is it possible to retain the default window's style and just remove the close button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prism has an attached property to set a style for the dialog window in the dialog `UserControl` markup. There, you can set the [`WindowStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.windowstyle?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) to [`None`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.windowstyle?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#fields) to remove the buttons and title.

```
<UserControl ...>
   <mvvm:Dialog.WindowStyle>
      <Style TargetType="Window">
         <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
      </Style>
   </mvvm:Dialog.WindowStyle>
   <!-- ...other markup. -->
</UserControl>
```

If this does not fulfill your requirements, you will have to create a custom dialog window.

- [Register a Custom Dialog Window](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/dialog-service.html#register-a-custom-dialog-window)

There you could customize everything, even create your own buttons and title bar, e.g.:

```
<Window x:Class="MCOSMOS.Infrastructure.Interactivity.Confirmations.ConfirmationWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">
   <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
      <WindowChrome GlassFrameThickness="1"
                    CaptionHeight="0"
                    ResizeBorderThickness="1"
                    UseAeroCaptionButtons="False"
                    NonClientFrameEdges="Bottom"/>
   </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
   <Window.Template>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
         <DockPanel Background="White">
            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                          Text="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
               <Button Grid.Column="1"
                       Focusable="False"
                       Content="X">
               </Button>
            </Grid>
            <ContentPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
         </DockPanel>
      </ControlTemplate>
   </Window.Template>
</Window>
```

In this case, your could either add a `Click` event handler to the close `Button` or bind a command to it in order to add your custom behavior.

Another option of using the default window style, but changing how the close button works is to create a custom dialog window that adds a handler to the `Closed` event. Then you can put your custom behavior there. It will be called before the `DialogService` from Prism handles the event.

```
public partial class YourCustomDialogWindow : Window, IDialogWindow
{
   public YourCustomDialogWindow()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      Closed += OnClosed;
   }
   
   public IDialogResult Result { get; set; }
   
   private void OnClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      // Check for null to make sure no other button caused closing.
      if (DialogResult is null)
      {
         var dataContext = (YourDataContext)DataContext;
         // ...do something, call a method and set a result.
      }
   }
}
```

In general, instead of casting to a concrete data context type, you could provide your own interface to make the dialog with this mechanism reusable instead of hard-wired to a single data context.

Yet another option to solve the issue in a general way is to create your own `DialogService` by deriving from the default implementation and changing how closing is handled. Overwrite the `ConfigureDialogWindowEvents` method, copy the [default implementation here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/551b4554da6d33f52c36124fbdb908e15477cf75/src/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Services/Dialogs/DialogService.cs#L140) and customize the `closedHandler`, e.g.:

```
EventHandler closedHandler = null;
closedHandler = (o, e) =>
    {
        // ...

        if (dialogWindow.Result == null)
            dialogWindow.Result = // ...get and set your result.

        // ...
    };
dialogWindow.Closed += closedHandler;
```

Please be aware that these approaches *assume* that all other methods of closing the dialog will set an `IDialogResult`, so that you can be sure that a value of `null` means the dialog was closed through an external mechanism like the close button.